# Render a template as string in a service in Grails 3 rest-api profile app

Tags: spring, grails, grails3

I've created a Grails `3.2.1` app with `rest-api` profile and want to render a GSP template as a String. For this I first added, `apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"` in `build.gradle` then based on the code of [ResponseRenderer](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v3.2.1/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/grails/artefact/controller/support/ResponseRenderer.groovy#L310), I tried following to render my GSP template as:

```
def viewResolver = applicationContext.getBean(CompositeViewResolver.BEAN_NAME, CompositeViewResolver)

View view = viewResolver.resolveView("/email-templates/signup", null)
```

But the `view` object is always `null`. Then I tried the following as well without success:

```
[ViewResolverComposite, GroovyMarkupViewResolver, GenericGroovyTemplateViewResolver].each {
    def viewResolver = applicationContext.getBean(it)

    View view = viewResolver.resolveViewName("/email-templates/signup", null)
    println view?.dump()
}
```

My template is located at `grails-app/views/emails-templates/_signup.gsp`.

In Grails 2, it was quite simple by injecting `groovyPageRenderer` bean of type [PageRenderer](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v3.2.1/grails-web-gsp/src/main/groovy/grails/gsp/PageRenderer.groovy) but I think, that bean and class is no longer used in Grails 3.

Comment: Everything is still there, the `PageRenderer` class is in the grails-web-gsp jar. I assume the problem is that adding the `grails-gsp` plugin doesn't provide enough of the needed classpath. See if adding `compile 'org.grails:grails-web-gsp:3.2.1'` helps

Comment: No @BurtBeckwith, adding that dependency didn't help

Comment: @BurtBeckwith After adding the dependency, the `groovyPageRenderer` was still not available as a bean in the context but I created a fresh 3.2.1 app with web profile and the `groovyPageRenderer` was there. The doc says about the rest profile: **Defaults to using JSON views for rendering responses (see the next section)** Any idea?  Need to compare the `build.config`.

Comment: So I searched the `groovyPageRenderer` in GitHub code and found out that the bean is being registered in the [grails-plugin-gsp](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/246b7264e8a638ada188ddba7a7a8812ba153399/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/GroovyPagesGrailsPlugin.groovy) plugin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Grails 3 app created with `web` profile, they can always use the `groovyPageRenderer` as given in the link [Grails render view from service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132521/grails-render-view-from-service).

And for the app created with `rest-api` profile, they just need to add the following in `build.gradle` under `dependencies` block:

```
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp:3.2.1"
```

And the above link will also work as is.

Just for the sake of description, inject the bean and use the `render` method:

```
PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer

def someMethod() {
    println groovyPageRenderer.render(template: "/email-templates/signup", model: [foo: "bar"])
}
```

Comment: Not working for me in Grails 3.3.5. The groovyPageRenderer is always null, even after adding the dependencies of grails-gsp plugin.

Comment: They must have renamed the bean's name

Comment: Its the same, The plugin is not loading and I am not able to find a reason why the plugin is not getting initialised.

Comment: Although the bean name is same, they have changed the artefact id of the plugin due to which the plugin is not getting initialised. I have added another answer to address the same.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

For Grails 3.3.x, few plugins have been externalized and artefact ids has changed.

Please refer [here](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#_externalized_plugins).

So, to make sure that `groovyPageRenderer` bean is registered, add

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
```

to the `dependencies block` in `build.gradle` instead of

```
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp"
```

Just to make sure the plugin is initialised successfully in your app, add

```
logger('grails.plugins', TRACE)
```

in the `logback.groovy` file. You should see something like this in the console logs.

```
Grails plug-in [groovyPages] with version [3.3.x] loaded successfully
```

For `compiling GSP files` and adding it to the `war/jar` package, add

```
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
```

to your `build.gradle` file.

I hope this helps.